# Table Background Color Change on New Event in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that is made up of tables grouped by a field called EventID in the Event dataset. It has been requested by the user that the background for the tables to alternate on each event. This used to be an easy task in Crystal Reports and I'm wondering if this is possible in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do it using the expression on the background color. If you select row go to the `BackgroundColor` property and then select expression

If you don't have any groups then simply use

```
 = IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#EAEAEA", "Transparent")
```

If you have single group then use

```
 = IIf(RowNumber("EventIDGroupName") Mod 2 = 0, "#EAEAEA", "Transparent")
```

You can also use this to “reset” the row color count within each group. If you want the first detail row in each sub group to start with White and this solution (when used on the detail row) allowed that to happen

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields![Name].Value, CountDistinct, "NameOfPartnetGroup") Mod 2, "White", "#EAEAEA")
```

for group headers/footers:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(*group on field*,CountDistinct,"*parent group name*") Mod 2,"White","AliceBlue")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is acutally pretty easy to implement with a block of code and an expression for background color.

1. **Write the code to deteremine what color to render and place it in the Reports|Code text box on the Reports Properties Page.** *The code below is by no means complete.*

   Public _lastEventID As Integer=-1

   Public Function GetBackgroundColor(eventID As Integer) AS String
       Dim color As String="White"
       if(_eventID<>_lastEventID) Then
           'CHANGE SOMETHING
           _lastEventID=eventID
       End If
       Return color End Function
2. **Add an expression in the BackgroundColor of the item you want to paint to refrerence the function created to return color.**

**Expression**
=Code.GetBackgroundColor(Fields!EventID.Value)